# Pandas compute time delta on filtered datasets

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timedelta

If I make up some time series data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import seed

# seed random number generator
seed(1)

time = pd.date_range('6/28/2021', periods=100, freq='1min')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=100), index=time,columns=['data'])

df.plot(figsize=(25,8))
```

This will plot:

[image]

And then filter the data for when `data` is above 50:
`df = df.loc[df['data'] > 50]`

How do I compute the time delta for when the data is above the value of 50? ONLY above the value of 50. For example if I do this:

```
# Compute delta time 
df['time_delta'] = df.index.to_series().diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')

df.time_delta.sum()
```

I dont think the sum is correct as this will include a time delta for when the data was below the value of 50, hope fully that makes sense to ONLY retrieve a time delta for when the value was above 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want:

```
df["timedelta"] = df.index.to_series().diff().where(df["data"].gt(50))

>>> df["timedelta"].sum()
Timedelta('0 days 00:44:00')
```

Which should be correct because there are exactly 44 rows where "data" is above 50 and each of these corresponds to a 1 minute time difference:

```
>>> df["data"].gt(50).sum()
44
```

Comment: I realized the column was the data, not the timestamp (I should sleep more :p)

Comment: Hehe, it's always good to sleep more :p

Comment: On my real data set, where timedelta.sum() is `1 days 12:09:02` Does that mean 1 day 12 hours 9 minutes and 2 seconds?

Comment: @HenryHub - Yup, correct!

Answer (score 0):

You can `mask` the data after computing the `diff`:

```
df.index.to_series().diff().mask(df['data'].le(50)).sum()
```

output: `Timedelta('0 days 00:44:00')`